# Subfolder in Sftp server

Tags: html, webserver

Can I create a subfolder on my server like **developer**.apple.com and **m**.facebook.com. Or do I need to buy the domain?

Comment: I'm not sure you know what "subfolder" or "domain" mean in this context.  You can create all the subfolders you want on your server's file system.  You can create all the routes you want on your exposed URL resources.  As for domains, if you have a domain (like `apple.com`) then you can create all of the sub-domains you'd like (`something.apple.com` or `another.apple.com` and so on), but you'll need to create DNS entries for them to people will be able to find them.  So owning the domain is one step, controlling the DNS is another.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you mean are "subdomains" not subfolders. It depends on your provider how you set up subdomains for your domain, usually in an control panel. So, if you own e.g. apple.com, you can have subdomains like dev.apple.com, iPhone.apple.com, etc.

Short answer: you only need to buy apple.com

Btw: it works the same for www. - it is also a subdomain, most domains forward e.g. apple.com to www.apple.com automatically.